# Intent-filter Browsable for and android Application, not Activity?

Tags: java, android, ios, android-activity, intentfilter

In iOS, there is a way to register custom scheme, and it is possible to open a whole app, like new instance or one with some app state (running) and it is not just a single ViewController.

For Android i am looking for a way to have whole stack of activity recovered (that might be launched before launching a browser) after user clicks a link that redirects to my app.

I don't want user to have to tap back till he closes the browser and goes back to my app activities, and I don't want to launch just single derived activity - but just go back to my app activity stack with the new one on the top.

Is this possible to achieve in some neat and clean way? Or at least clean activities of the app that were launched before a browser where user clicks a link that opens my app's activity?

Comment: I hope I understood you question correctly. I think that is what happens when user clicks home button an goes on to do some other work. The stack gets saved and when user wants to et back to your app, he/she long presses the home button and chooses your ap which went to background. Until Android removes it due to resource limitations, the stack of activities remain in the same state as user left it. User can start from the same place where he/she left the app.

Comment: That's right, but i wanted to achieve same effect as if user went back to my app upon running my app's intent for new Activity from the browser.

Comment: Are you starting the browser from within your app?

Comment: Nope. It is external library that is loading my house ad - Admob. This ad is redirecting to some url that redirects back to my custom scheme url that is being recognized by an app, iOS (which wouldn't recognize http schemes) or Android. I can already say that i can't make ad redirect to custom scheme url because ads provider doesn't allow for that (mediations and so on :/ ).

Comment: I think then just don't finish() your activities in `onStop` or `onPause`. If a browse is strated from add withion you app, then it should automatically be on same activity after you close the browser.

Comment: I am not finishing on those events, it wouldn't have any sense. I can't force admob to launch custom event on certain ad, even if (AppEventListener is not being called) i am not allowed to fetch certain ad details (only by reflection , but it's dirty) and launch a browser in my activity or some custom events :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33793/discussion-between-shobhit-puri-and-y-a-p)

Comment: Any ideas? If that would be possible to launch an instance of an app (browsable) instead of sole activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to create launching activity that would be browsable. This activity would then launch desired activity with flags :

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

and immediately finish itself...